Swift Vision to detect box dimensions
I want to allow uses to measure box dimensions within an app.
On my iPhone camera I noticed I could measure an object by moving the camera along the object. How can I present a camera in SwiftUI that allows the user to take 3 measurements (W, H, L)? Also is there a way to use the Vision framework to detect a rectangular object in an image and get its dimensions?
sample copy-paste able code that doesn't really work.
import UIKit
import Vision

func detectBoxDimensions(in image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (CGRect?) -> Void) {
   guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
       completion(nil)
       return
   }
   
   let request = VNDetectRectanglesRequest { request, error in
       guard let results = request.results as? [VNRectangleObservation],
             let box = results.first else {
           completion(nil)
           return
       }
       
       // Convert the normalized coordinates to image coordinates
       let imageWidth = CGFloat(cgImage.width)
       let imageHeight = CGFloat(cgImage.height)
       
       // Get the bounding box for the detected rectangle
       let boundingBox = box.boundingBox
       let boxFrame = CGRect(
           x: boundingBox.origin.x * imageWidth,
           y: (1 - boundingBox.origin.y - boundingBox.height) * imageHeight,
           width: boundingBox.width * imageWidth,
           height: boundingBox.height * imageHeight
       )
       
       completion(boxFrame)
   }
   
   request.minimumAspectRatio = VNAspectRatio(0.5)
   request.maximumAspectRatio = VNAspectRatio(1.5)
   
   let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
   
   DispatchQueue.global().async {
       do {
           try handler.perform([request])
       } catch {
           print("Error performing rectangle detection: \(error)")
           completion(nil)
       }
   }
}


VNDetectRectanglesRequest only returns 2D results, there is no Z. Vision has no understanding of depth. You would have to feed it more than a 2D image. Would need a depth map and camera info to estimate physical distance. You might be able to calculate distance yourself with that data too.

@loremipsum how do I obtain a depth map and the camera info you suggested?

Some cameras add depth data and camera data to the images. The depth data you can get from AI too. If you are using the iPhones’s cameras you can get it yourself with the LIDAR sensor.
